# Store values of dynamically added fields to array in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have two dropdowns(X & Y) created using spring mvc , and an "Add" button. 
When the "Add" button is pressed, it adds a pair of these dropdowns (ie. dynamically added html).
When the form is submitted, 
**"I want to store all values of dropdown X to xIds[] and all values of dropdown Y to yIds[]."**

My Spring model contains:

```
private String[] xIds;
private String[] yIds;
```

**I tried:**

```
<form:select path="xIds"></...> <form:select path="yIds"></...>
<form:select path="xIds"></...> <form:select path="yIds"></...>
....
```

for all the X dropdowns and similarly for Y dropdowns. But it says "bean property xIds not found".

How should I do this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Had problems with name attribute of these select tags, that is why it was giving error. It works!